# Lost connection between native and flutter code

Tags: flutter, kotlin

Steps to reproduce

1. From flutter code, start another Android Activity via MethodChannel

   private MethodChannel.Result _result;

   ```
    @Override
    public void configureFlutterEngine(@NonNull FlutterEngine flutterEngine) {
        super.configureFlutterEngine(flutterEngine);
        new MethodChannel(flutterEngine.getDartExecutor().getBinaryMessenger(), CHANNEL)
                .setMethodCallHandler(
                        (call, result) -> {
                            _result = result; //Store
                            Intent intent = new Intent(this, SecondActivity.class);
                            startActivityForResult(intent, RQ_CODE);
                        }
                );
    }
   ```
2. Run a heavy task on the second activity, I cannot share my code but we can simulate by creating multiple large list

   for (int i = 0; i < 200; i++) {
   String[] arrays = new String[10000000];
   System.out.println(i);
   }
3. Call finish to back to `MainActivity`. Now, the _result was destroyed

   @Override
   public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
   super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
   System.out.printf("onActivityResult %d %d; %s%n", requestCode, resultCode, this);
   if (requestCode == RQ_CODE && _result != null) {
   _result.success(resultCode);
   System.out.println("_result " + _result.toString());
   } else
   System.out.println("_result null");
   }

I created a sample project here https://github.com/thanhbinh84/flutter-memory-issue
and reported bug here https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/132951
But I don't know when it could be fixed.